# How to run MsBuild in Jenkins scrippted pipeline correctly?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I am using scrippted pipeline in Jenkins and I want to compile a solution using MsBuild.
Problem is when I run it using bat command: `bat ' MsBuild.exe solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug'` (which runs it as a batch file) and when the build **FAILS** the **job doesn't fail.**
It's like it doesn't recognize that the MsBuild failed to compile the solution and continues to the next steps.

How can I run MsBuild and analize the output so that if the build fails, then the job will fail too?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you’re doing the very same like we are doing. However for us it is working. By chance do you catch any exception which might have been thrown by the bat call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following and see how it goes:

```
def msbuild =  "path/to/msbuild/MsBuild.exe"
def exitStatus = bat(returnStatus: true, script: "${msbuild} solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug")
if (exitStatus != 0){
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```

And if you don't want to execute it any further, you can throw an error if exit status is not 0:

```
if (exitStatus != 0){
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    error 'build failed'
}
```